# Modrewrite is not sending $_GET params

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I am trying to rewrite my urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^help/(.+)/(.+) help.php?helpid=$2
RewriteRule ^city/(.+)/(.+) city.php?cityid=$2
```

And even that the url contains the expected format: http://example.com/help/the-irelevant-title/5/

it seems that

`isset($_GET['helpid']))` will allways fire `false` in `help.php`

Usually this system worked for me. Is there something I am missing here?

-EDIT-

As I can see that this should work (or at least one of you answers) I'm adding more code to the question:

**Full .htaccess content**

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 500 /oohps.php
ErrorDocument 404 /oohps.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^help/([^/]+)/([^/]+) help.php?helpid=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^city/([^/]+)/([^/]+) city.php?cityid=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
```

**Beggining of help.php**

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$_GET['noseo'] = true;
include('htmlhead.php');
/* Leemos la id del grupo*/
$selected;
if(isset($_GET['helpid'])){
    $selected = $_GET['helpid'];
}else {
    echo '<script>alert("Modrewrite fails. Id is missing, id: '.$_GET['helpid'].'");location.href = "/"</script>';   /* Allways returns this*/
}
```

Comment: Make sure MultiViews is disabled, otherwise Apache may map /help/ to help.php without using mod_rewrite

Answer (score 3):

The regex is too greedy with the frist `.+` matching the slashes too causing the remainder of the regex to fail. The `[^/]+` regex will match anything but the slash.

```
RewriteRule ^help/([^/]+)/([^/]+) help.php?helpid=$2
RewriteRule ^city/([^/]+)/([^/]+) city.php?cityid=$2
```

Comment: It is also possible to use non-greedy quantifier: `^help/(.+?)/(.+)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `[QSA]` should work to forward the GET params. Also, changing `.+` (greedy) to `[^/]+` (meaning any character that isn't a slash repeated 1 or more times), it should fix your problem.

```
RewriteRule ^help/([^/]+)/([^/]+) help.php?helpid=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^city/([^/]+)/([^/]+) city.php?cityid=$2 [QSA]
```

It can also be shortened to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(help|city)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1.php?$1id=$3 [QSA]
```

[From the apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.
>
> Consider the following rule:
>
> RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA]
>
> With the [QSA] flag, a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped to /page.php?page=123&one=two. Without the [QSA] flag, that same request will be mapped to /page.php?page=123 - that is, the existing query string will be discarded.

Comment: QSA doesn't apply, his initial url doesn't seem to have a query string.  He's trying to go from /help/foo/bar to /help.php?helpid=bar

Comment: The QSA-Flag is used to append an existing Query to the rewritten url, it would turn /help/title/5/?param=1 into help.php?helpid=5&param=1. You do not have to handle the query. This is quite useful, but is not the right answer here.

Comment: @SamDufel I got aware of that now, and updated my OP before you wrote your answer to specify that this is simply for others googling the same question.

Comment: I loved this 'RewriteRule ^(help|city)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1.php?$1id=$3 [QSA]'  +1

Answer (score 1):

is there a reason you have two variables? this works though:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^help/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ help.php?helpid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^city/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ city.php?cityid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: yes, the first variable is due SEO. I know i just need the id but yes, in this case i need it to give the URL relevant keywords

Comment: made an edit that does what you need. someone else already gave essentially the same answer though.

Comment: not sure, it seems fine on my end? a better way of handling seo type stuff like this is to do something like RewriteRule ^help/([^/\.]+)/?$ help.php?helpid=$2 [L] and then calling the script via something like /help/53-this_is_the_title and then exploding off the - to get the id or frameworks like CakePHP support this natively

Answer (score 1):

You may try this in the .htaccess file in root directory:

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*              %1.php?%1id=%2             [L]
```

Redirects

`http://domain.com/par1/anything/par2` with or without trailing slash

To

`http://domain.com/par1.php?par1id=par2`

Strings `par1`, `anything` and `par2` are assumed to be dynamic and, according to the examples in the question,  `par1` is the name of the PHP script and also the first part of the `key` name in the redirected query.

Example when `par1` = **help**:

Redirects:

`http://domain.com/help/the-irelevant-title/5/`

To:

`http://domain.com/help.php?helpid=5`

For permanent redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`

---

Although I did not test the other rules and don't know if they work as expected, the .htaccess file in the question should be modified like this to include the rule-set in this answer:

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 500 /oohps.php
ErrorDocument 404 /oohps.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*              %1.php?%1id=%2             [L]

# Next line is a suggested addition to prevent loops.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^login$   login.php         [L]
```

Comment: Actually just by adding 'Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews' Did the fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. That's something I thought it was missing and could be the cause of the problem, but I also combined the 2 rules into a single one. Maybe it will be better and more versatile to have them that way.